# dplyr::summarize() returning NAs for means

Tags: r, dplyr, time, time-series, summarize

I want to create a dataset for visualizing daily min, max and mean temperatures using a digraph. I have a time series dataset with the dates in one column (datetimestamp) and water quality (temp, pH, etc.) variables in proceeding columns. Data is reported in 15 minute intervals. There are NAs in the dataset where the sensor malfunctioned.

Here is what the header of the data frame ldq1 looks like:

```
 datetimestamp temp 
1  2007-01-01 00:00:00 16.4  
2  2007-01-01 00:15:00 16.4  
3  2007-01-01 00:30:00 16.4  
4  2007-01-01 00:45:00 16.4  
5  2007-01-01 01:00:00 16.4  
6  2007-01-01 01:15:00 16.4  
7  2007-01-01 01:30:00 16.3  
8  2007-01-01 01:45:00 16.2  
9  2007-01-01 02:00:00 16.3  

The datetimestamp class:
class(ldq1$datetimestamp)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

temp is double.

I am summarizing daily maxes, mins and means like this:

```
l<-ldq1 %>%
+   group_by(date = as.Date(datetimestamp)) %>%
+   summarise(t_min = min(temp, na.rm = TRUE),
+             t_max = max(temp, na.rm = TRUE),
+             t_mean = mean(temp, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

But the output looks like this:

```
Warning message:
There were 6705 warnings in `summarise()`.
The first warning was:
ℹ In argument: `t_min = min(temp, na.rm = TRUE)`.
ℹ In group 187: `date = 2007-07-06`.
Caused by warning in `min()`:
! no non-missing arguments, returning NA
```

```
l

# A tibble: 5,845 × 4
   date       t_min t_max t_mean
   <date>     <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
 1 2007-01-01 15.7  17.1      NA
 2 2007-01-02 15.2  16.7      NA
 3 2007-01-03 14.7  15.7      NA
 4 2007-01-04 15.3  16.1      NA
 5 2007-01-05 15.6  16.9      NA
 6 2007-01-06 15.9  17.3      NA
 7 2007-01-07 16.3  17.8      NA
 8 2007-01-08 16.7  17.8      NA
 9 2007-01-09 16    17.5      NA
10 2007-01-10 14.7  16.7      NA
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO, GuyRachel, and great first question! Unfortunately ... I cannot reproduce the error. Even when I replace one of the `temp` values with `NA`, the error does not present. Please find a sample of your data (using `head`, `sample`, _something_) that reproduces the problem, then [edit] your question to add it. Since your data has `POSIXt` data, it is often best (easier and more accurate) for us if you paste the output from `dput(x)` (where `x` is the _sample of data_) into a [code block]; the dput output (has `structure(..` through matching `)`) is unambiguous and always works.

Comment: Verify that the "temp" column are numeric values and not character strings with: `class(ldq1$temp)`

Comment: Since `t_min` and `t_max` are outputting character strings, it seems very likely your `temp` is character and not numeric. `min` and `max` work on character strings (but alphabetically, so 11 is less than 9) but `mean` does not, so that would explain your results.

Comment: For the reasons mentioned by r2evans and Jon, I am voting to close this question down as not reproducible

Answer (score 0):

As @Dave2e and @Jon Spring already mentioned, the problem is that your `temp` column is coded as a character variable instead of being numeric. Thus, you just need to add a step to do this transformation, using `mutate` and `across`.

```
ldq1 %>%
  # Transform temp from char to numeric
  mutate(across(temp, ~as.numeric(.x))) %>%
  group_by(date = as.Date(datetimestamp)) %>%
  summarise(t_min = min(temp, na.rm = TRUE),
            t_max = max(temp, na.rm = TRUE),
            t_mean = mean(temp, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')

# A tibble: 1 × 4
#  date       t_min t_max t_mean
#  <date>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 2007-01-01  16.2  16.4   16.4
```